# manage.py makemigrations works but manage.py migrate did not

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho891.png)

how to solve the error.I first created the model with only one class and the makemigrations and migrate work perfect.
but now i add another class in model but now migrate did not work the output is in pic.
django version is 1.11
and i also register it in admin.py

Comment: Read djnago documentation on [migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/) for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

`python manage.py makemigrations` ----> for all app

`python manage.py makemigrations app_name` ----> for a specific app

`python manage.py migrate` ----> for all the apps,

N.B. = `migrate` doesnt take any `app name` , you need to run only `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: thanku sir. but after using this the error remain same(when adding data to table.Error come up. saying no such table exist corces_step)

Comment: first of all drop your database, create a new one and delete all the migrations files except init.py, then follow the steps

Comment: done sir. now when i do migrate some applying --- lines appears . but when in django admin i add data in field example title="dssda" etc and press save again table not found exception occur